# Git Pull trying to overwrite ignored files

Tags: git

I am running a git pull, but i am getting the following error:

```
 error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    config.js
 Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
 Aborting
```

My gitignore file looks like this:

```
config.js
Gruntfile.js
```

Why is git trying to overwrite a file that I told to ignore? Also, how can I pull all the files I need without overwriting my config files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just because a file is ignored doesn't mean it wasn't first checked in by you or somebody else.

Have a look at

```
git log config.js
```

Do what it says, move the file out of the way, git pull then move it back. You may need to run

```
git rm --cached config.js
```